# Why when instantiating objects they are in the air and not on ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Circle part put the objects in the air.
How can i make that they will be on the ground ?
They are standing in the air. When using the square formation they are on ground but with the circle they are in the air.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle
    }

    public Transform squadMemeber;
    public int columns = 4;
    public int space = 10;
    public int numObjects = 20;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ChangeFormation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        Formation formation = Formation.Square;

        switch (formation)
        {
            /*case Formation.Square:

                for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
                {
                    Transform go = Instantiate(squadMemeber);
                    Vector3 pos = FormationSquare(i);
                    go.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
                    go.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
                }
                break;*/

            case Formation.Circle:

                Vector3 center = transform.position;
                for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 5.0f);
                    var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
                    Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    Vector2 FormationSquare(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * space;
        float posY = (index / columns) * space;
        return new Vector2(posX, posY);
    }

    Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        float ang = Random.value * 360;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }
}
```

[image: In air]

They should be instantiating on the ground(Terrain).
Need to position them on the ground.

Update:

This is what i tried now.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadFormation : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle
    }

    public Transform squadMemeber;
    public int columns = 4;
    public int space = 10;
    public int numObjects = 20;
    public float yOffset = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ChangeFormation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        Formation formation = Formation.Circle;

        switch (formation)
        {
            /*case Formation.Square:

                for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
                {
                    Transform go = Instantiate(squadMemeber);
                    Vector3 pos = FormationSquare(i);
                    go.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
                    go.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));
                }
                break;*/

            case Formation.Circle:

                Vector3 center = transform.position;
                for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 5.0f);
                    var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
                    pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
                    pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
                    Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    Vector2 FormationSquare(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * space;
        float posY = (index / columns) * space;
        return new Vector2(posX, posY);
    }

    Vector3 RandomCircle(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        float ang = Random.value * 360;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }
}
```

I added a offset yOffset and this two lines inside the for loop:

```
pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
```

Now they are on the ground but lie down on the back/stomach and not standing like they were in the air.

[image: lie down]

Comment: You just asked 5 questions....It doesn't work like this and no one should go around writing a code that can do all these. Modify your question and chose one question only and then show a code that you tried. When you get an answer, you create a new question with your second question....

Comment: To answer your question thats in your title, objects instantiate at (0,0) i believe. Could be mistaken.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet No. Terrain have different height in different location. You have to use Raycast or SampleHeight  to get the height. 0,0 wont do it unless you expect every height to be 0,0.

Comment: No, I'm saying the default is 0,0, if my memory serves me right. Not height. Where the object instantiates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when instantiating objects they are in the air and not on ground?

You need to find a way to calculate the height of the terrain then use that as your y-axis value.

After you get your pos, modify the y-axis with the [`Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html) function.

```
Vector3 pos = RandomCircle(center, 5.0f);
pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
```

Maybe add an offset depending on the type of the GameObject(The `yOffset` should be a float)

```
pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
```

Now, go ahead and instantiate with that new `pos`:

```
var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);
Instantiate(squadMemeber, pos, rot);
```

Note:

Depending on the size of your character,you must and have to keep changing the value of the `yOffset` until you get the position you want. This position should work well for the-same character. If you want to do this to the GameObjects with different size, you also have to modify the `yOffset` until you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I added this line at the top public float yOffset = 1; then this two lines in the for loop: pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
                    pos.y = pos.y + yOffset; now they are on the ground but they are lie down on the back not standing as they were in the air.

Comment: It would be better to add another EDIT in your question with your new code and screenshot of what looks like now. That will make it easier to know exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Edited my original question with what i did.

Comment: Lol that's some funny picture. It looks like the problem is from here `var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);`. Comment that out for a sec then test it. If the problem is fixed, move `var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);`  before `pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);`. See the edit I made in your question. `var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(pos - center);` is likely the problem.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, but some advice:

I see some basic problem here with your code being kind of confused anyway. There are some things that should be similar that aren't. I think the baseline here is that you need some basic structure.

First things first, you should start with identifying the basic parts you need here.

There are three basic things to resolve:

1. XY-position
2. Z-position
3. rotation

Last one is the issue with your characters lying on the ground. See the rotation by -90 degrees for the square? I assume that this one does this.

But a more pressing matter here, here is a question for you: Aside from the XY-position, what should be the difference between squares and circles? Answer: none. You treat both cases far more different than they should be. The code should look somewhat like this:

```
Position xyPosition;
switch (formation)
    case Circle: xyPosition = randomCirclePosition(someargument)
    case Square: xyPosition = randomSquarePosition(someargument)
Position position = rotateUpright(xyPosition)
position = adjustZ(position)
```

See how the difference is applied only at one part?

The thing that jumps to my eyes immediately are those signatures: `Vector2 FormationSquare` and `Vector3 RandomCircle`. In particular, `Vector2` and `Vector3`. Those are two entirely different approaches. Why? This makes your code unnecessarily heterogeneous, makes it harder to read. Does not allow for the clear structure I wrote above. Why did you derive that much? Why didn't you copy the old code of the square and then adjusted it as needed?

Do I assume correct when I say that you copied the square code from the internet? And that you have troubles understanding it for some reason? Maybe because you are not familiar with the math behind it? If so, my "answer" is this: Take the square code and do not continue until you understand any single line it it. What it does, why it is needed, what happens without it. Perfectly fine if you simply go and outcomment lines, then look what happens in the engine. Or ask somebody. But it is most important that you understand every single line in the end.

You also might want to put the code on CodeReview when it is working. I see some issues here and there in style. Like the mysterious 23 that comes out of nothing.

Sorry if this sounded a little headstrong or the like, or if I misjudge the situation here.